# Disable or change {{}} delimiters in web2py templates?

Tags: jquery, templates, plugins, web2py

I'm implementing a web app using web2py and jQuery. I want to use the [jquery template plugin](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl) but the plugin uses the same notation for templates as web2py; `{{ jQuery code }}` and collides with web2py templates.

Is there any way I can disable web2py templates or escape the `{{` and `}}` parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable web2py templating my simply haing the controller functions return a string instead. You may also want to consider this option: in jquery-tmpl.js you can replace

```
/{{(\/?)(\w+|.)(?:\((.*?)\))?(?: (.*?))?}}/g
```

with

```
/{%(\/?)(\w+|.)(?:\((.*?)\))?(?: (.*?))?%}/g
```

and use `{%...%}` in place of `{{...}}` so no more conflict with web2py syntax. Similarly we have add an option to web2py to switch syntax there. If this is critical bring it up on the web2py mailing list.

Comment: I think for switching syntax in web2py we should wait for what templating will get into jquery core.

Comment: web2py cannot switch because we promis backward compatibility. We can give different options. Anyway, I agree. let's wait and see. Using {{..}} would not be a good idea for them since it conflicts with JS.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, I just implemented arbitrary delimiters in web2py trunk. Now you can do in a controller:

```
def render(filename,**variables):
    context = globals()
    context.update(variables)
    from gluon.template import render
    return render(filename=os.path.join(request.folder,'views',filename),
                  path=os.path.join(request.folder,'views'),
                  context=context,delimiters=('{%','%}'))

def index():
    return render('default/index.html',message='hello world')
```

and in default/index.html:

```
{%=message%}
```

This is very new (5 mins ago) so give it a try and let me know if it works for you. Please follow up on our mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to replace

```
/\${([^}]*)}/g, "{{= $1}}
```

with

```
/\${([^}]*)}/g, "{%= $1%}
```

but after that it works fine. Thank you!